# reading from a matrix, allocated with malloc, AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c, matrix, header, malloc

So i'm writing a matrix which contains a struct pixel. The code seems to write the standard pixel into the matrix, but when i try to print out the content, it seems to point to a wrong address, because the AddressSanitizer is coming up, that printf is reading from a wrong address:
Here is the code that for allocating with the test printf():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrx.h"
#include "pixel.h"

void matr_initializer(struct matrix* matr, int w, int h){

matr->height = h;
matr->width = w;
struct pixel p;
standardPixel(&p);
matr->grid = (struct pixel**)malloc(sizeof(struct pixel)*w);

if(matr->grid == NULL){
   fprintf(stderr,"Irgendwas lief beim allozieren verkehrt");
   abort();
}

for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
   matr->grid[i] = (struct pixel*)malloc(sizeof(matr->grid)*h);
}

for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){
     matr->grid[i][j] = p;
   /*Here is the printf that causes the error*/
     printf("%d %d %d ",matr->grid[i][j].r,matr->grid[i][j].g,matr->grid[i][j].b);
}
   printf("\n");
}


 matr->n = w*h;
 matr->init = 1;

}
```

Here is are the header files i'm using:

```
 #ifndef _MATRH_
 #define _MATRH_
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "pixel.h"
 // typedef struct matrix matrix;

 struct matrix{
 int height;
 int width;
 struct pixel*  spalten;
 struct pixel** grid;
 int n;
 int init;
 };

 void matr_initializer(struct matrix* matr, int w, int h);


 void printf_matr_color(struct matrix* matr);

 void printf_matr_RGB(struct matrix* matr);
 #endif
```

And the pixel.h

```
#ifndef _PIXELH_
#define _PIXELH_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct pixel{
  int color;
  int r,g,b;
  int brightness;
  int energy;
};

void standardPixel(struct pixel* p);
#endif
```

Comment: Ideally this could be solved by using gdb. But you could make your life easier by doing `matr->grid = (struct pixel*)malloc(sizeof(struct pixel) * w * h);`. What do you think `sizeof(matr->grid) * h` does?

Comment: That's true, i already thought about that, but now im curious, why this is not working, it didn't seem to have any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member `grid` of `struct matrix` is declared as a `struct pixel **`, and you appear intent on using it as a dynamically-allocated array of pointers to dynamically-allocated arrays.  This is fine.

Your allocation for `matr->grid` itself is odd, albeit not problematic in itself.  You allocate space sufficient for `w` instances of `struct pixel`, but what you actually intend to store there are `w` *pointers* to `struct pixel`.  The allocated space is large enough as long as a `struct pixel` is at least as large as a `struct pixel *`, but you really ought to avoid all doubt by allocating space that is assured to be of sufficient size, and that furthermore is not excessive.

Your allocations for the space pointed to by the member pointers `matr->grid` is where the more serious problem appears to lie.  For each one you allocate `sizeof(matr->grid)*h` bytes, but what you seem actually to want is `sizeof(struct pixel) * h` bytes.  Very likely a `struct pixel` is larger than `matr->grid` (a `struct pixel **`), in which case you are not allocating as much memory as you need.

This appears to be what you really want:

```
matr->grid = malloc(sizeof(*matr->grid) * w);
for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
   matr->grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(*matr->grid[i]) * h);
}
/* error checking omitted for brevity */
```

Things to note here:

- It is not necessary and generally not desirable to cast the return value of `malloc()` in C
- The `sizeof` operator does not evaluate its operand; it uses only the operand's *type* (with one exception that does not apply here).
- It is therefore valid to compute the number of bytes to allocate in terms of the size of the pointer's referrent, as demonstrated.  This ensures that you use the correct element size, even if you change the type of the pointer.

Additionally, be aware that although your indexing appears to be consistent with your allocation and dimensioning, the way you've done it, your grid is indexed by `[column][row]`.  It is much more typical to arrange to index by `[row][column]`, instead.

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer to my allocating problem for the matrix the other day here on stackoverflow, because my tutor told me a wrong allocation on the fly, long story short, you sir, are my hero!